# Alternatives to SkyPE that can call "real" phone numbers

Tags: skype, alternatives

I currently pay SkyPE $3/month to make unlimited calls across the USA 
and Canada (ie, the NANPA "1" international dialing code), and, less 
importantly, pay them about $4 month for an inbound telephone number.

However, I'm unhappy with SkyPE's overall service and am concerned 
their Linux support may decline in the future.

I realize I probably won't find something as inexpensive, but what 
reasonably priced alternatives exist with the following features (all 
of which SkyPE has):

- no hardware required, softphone only
- ability to call "real" phone numbers, not just other free SIP users
- fixed monthly fee for unlimited calling (within reasonable use 
  criteria), not a per-minute plan
- ability to set caller ID to a number I own, either my non-SkyPE 
  cell phone number or a local number I purchase. Some "real" phone 
  numbers now auto-reject the caller ID "UNKNOWN" or its variants.
- ability to conference multiple phone numbers, ideally at no extra charge

Although SkyPE doesn't have this ability directly, I'd also like the 
ability to record both outbound and inbound phone calls, although I'd 
settle for a solution without this feature.

I have googled around, and here's what I've found:

- There are lots of free softphones around, but it's not clear to me 
  which ones can call "real" phone numbers and/or whether that's even 
  a sensible question. I'm pretty sure a real phone number has a SIP 
  address too, but I'm guessing you need some sort additional service 
  to actually reach that SIP address.
- There are lots of VOIP services out there, but many come with 
  their own box, and it's not clear whether they support softphones or 
  not.
- My overall sense is that I need to glue a softphone and a VOIP 
  service together, but it's not clear to me which softphones and 
  which VOIP services are gluable in Linux.

Ideally, I'd like a Linux friendly service, one that supports Linux, 
unlike some companies that allow Linux, but don't support it.

If no one has a specific solution, I'd appreciate knowing what key 
phrases/terms I should be googling for.

I believe this question is similar enough to 
[Secure FOSS alternative to Skype on Linux & OpenBSD?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9724) that it shouldn't be 
closed, but different enough that it warrants its own question.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but I'm not quite so sure about me 100% liking the placement here. We have [Hardware Recs](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and [Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but (afaict) no section for Product/Service recommendations. I'll upvote, but i'd also be in favor of migrating this somewhere better, if I knew of a better place.